# Use boot-clj to Create Correct About Information

Tags: clojure, boot-clj

I'm using boot to build a Clojure&ClojureScript project. Obviously it depends on a lot of third party libraries with all their licenses. Most of these licenses require mentioning the copyright of the dependency in the resulting deliverable.

I could not find a boot plugin or other hints how to create this information automatically at boot time. Has anyone ever solved this? Maintaining this list manually is tedious and error prone.

Comment: For the record: I am aware of [lein-licenses](https://github.com/technomancy/lein-licenses) and already tried to combine some functions I found there with the POM parsing and JAR extracting from `boot.pod` and the `boot.pom` worker. So far, it's just confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

At present there is no built-in or community tasks which provide this functionality.